# Apply pandas dataframe/series to netaddr EUI constructor

Tags: python, pandas, mac-address

I have a dataframe with Mac addresses, which needs converting. I first do the following to clear out any `nan`'s:

```
df = df[pd.notnull(df["MacAddr"])]["MacAddr"] # avoid null values being passed to netaddr
```

...then I'd like to parse into the `EUI` constructor like so:

```
from netaddr import EUI, mac_bare

mac = EUI(df)
mac.dialect = mac_bare
```

But this doesn't work, because EUI expects a string, not a pandas Series. Is there a way to circumvent this?

As an error I get this:

```
Name: MacAddr, Length: 26953, dtype: object is not str() or unicode()!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since parsing dataframes/series isn't currently possible for the EUI constructor, I created a function for `df.apply()`, like so:

```
def main(self):
    def _eui_mac_bare_func(x):
        mac = EUI(x)
        mac.dialect = mac_bare
        return mac

series = df[pd.notnull(df["MacAddr"])]["MacAddr"] # avoid null values being passed to netaddr
new_series = series.apply(_eui_mac_bare_func) # apply function to every row
df = df.join(new_series.rename("Norm_MacAddr")) # join df and series on corresponding indices
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list from the series, then join the elements into a string.

```
 ','.join(df[pd.notnull(df["MacAddr"])]["MacAddr"].to_list())
```

Comment: it appears the EUI constructor expects a certain format, so the long string is not compliant, unfortunately. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you've not figured it out post the formatting or working example of what is expected?